# SSRS-Reports formatting

Tags: reporting-services

I am having a few issues using SSRS-Reports 2005.

The first one is I am trying to use the `datediff` function to change the background color of a cell based on the two dates being within 30 days of each other.

```
=iif(
DateDiff("d",DateString,Fields!Insurance_Certificate.Value)<= 30, "Tan", "White"
)
```

I have my fields formatted through the initial query so they look like `mm/dd/yyyy`.  I guess my first question is how do I see what value is being evaluated because whatever this is returning can't be right.

Comment: Where is DateString coming from?

Answer (score 1):

> my [...] question is how do I see what value is being evaluated

There is no real "debugger" available like you would have in -say- a WinForms C# app. Instead, you have several "raw" "debugging" options:

- Render `Fields!Insureance_Certificate.Value` in a seperate cell, as text
- Render `DateDiff("d",DateString,Fields!Insurance_Certificate.Value)` in a seperate cell, as text
- Right-click your dataset, select "Query...", and execute the query manually. Inspect the values for your field. Make sure they're what you'd expect.
- Render your `DateString` in a seperate cell, with and without a cast to a date.

Other than that @MarkBannister has a great suggestion, using actual Dates as opposed to strings for your fields and variables. One additional thing to note about this, is that date parsing may be culture-specific. Be sure you understand and know in what culture your `DateString` is being parsed. The above "debugging" options may help you find out.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest querying your date fields as dates (instead of as strings), comparing them using the DateDiff function as in the question and formatting the date output using the `Format` property of the appropriate textboxes in SSRS.